# GIT Project with several projects

Tags: eclipse, git, mobile

I have a mobile app built with Titanium which I am selling to my customers.
I have a main source code that I update and then copy/modify the project for each customer and build for App Store. That was easy for 2-3 project but now I am having a big problem. I am new to Git and I wanted to ask if there is any way to manage this projects with ease. 
For example changing my source code and then push automatically the changes to other projects. Should I use branches to accomplish that?
Note:My source code folder is on the same folder on all projects so nothing changes there in the modification. I have other folder for UI customisation and other folder for images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually would have one project-agnostic `master` branch and several `projectX` branches. Anything specific to all projects would be developed on `master`. The `project` branches would merge all changes from `master`.

To switch your working tree between branches, you can use the command `git checkout projectX` command. Then use `git merge master` to import the commits from master.

Alternatively, when you want to have access to the sourcecode of all projects simultaneously, you can use separate repositories instead of branches. Create one master git repository and a separate git repository for each project in separate directories. On each project, set the master-repository as their origin to pull from. To import from the master-repository, you would then use `git pull` instead of `git merge`.

When you want to automatize the merging/pulling from the project branches/repositories, I would recommend you to use a shell-script which automatically does this for each project. For even more luxury, you can set this up as a [post-commit hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) for the master branch. But keep in mind that the pull might fail due to a merge conflict.

Answer (score 1):

The best advice is probably to take a day to familiarize yourself with git, read up on it as much as you can, and play around with it. Googling "[git workflows](https://www.google.com/search?q=git+workflows)" yields for example [these](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/centralized-workflow) two [documents](https://git-scm.herokuapp.com/book/en/v2/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows). The documentation often deals with the "distributed" workflows (with multiple people), but you can apply the same techniques for managing your project.

In short, yes, branches will help you here. Without more in-depth knowledge of your setup, I'd recommend one development branch, with all the per-client branches going off of it. Then you can periodically merge your development branch into the per-client branches to release your apps. If you work on multiple features at a time, you can also have feature branches that you merge into your development branch, which you then merge into your per-client branches.

To make this process as painless as possible, I'd try to automate things. Try to factor your per-app information into configuration files (either build time or run-time config) and have a common code base for all of them. Automate the build process as far as possible. If you encounter merge conflicts often when merging your branches, think about how you could refactor your code to solve this for the future.